# Loops in Python: not expecting this output

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am not getting why this is returning only one value as I am looping through a list.

```py
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    # Write your code here
    
    students_avg = []
    for j in students_marks:
        sume = 0
        for i in j:
            sume = sume+ i
        avg = sume/(len(j))
        students_avg.append(avg)
    print(students_avg)

    grade = []
    for item in students_avg:
        if item >= 90:
            grade.append('A+')
        elif 80<item<=90 :
            grade.append('A')
        elif 70<item<=80 :
            grade.append('B')
        elif 60<item<=70 :
            grade.append('C')
        elif 50<item<=60:
            grade.append('D')
        elif item < 50 :
            grade.append('F')
    print(grade)
```

I have tried with 2 elements in the list with [50.6,48] which only returns `F`.

This is the code I am trying to execute. I am getting the students_avg as the correct output. But when i pass that list through the 2nd for loop i am getting only single output

row 1 = [66, 61, 88, 26, 13] -- for student 1
row 2 = [52, 38, 7, 74, 62] -- for student 2

so we form a list of averages of students and pass that to get the grade . That's the problem .

Comment: after for you needs to be indented

Comment: That was indented in my jupyter notebook . this is the first time i am posting a question so had some issue

Comment: You're checking existence of a float in `range(x,y)`. `range(x,y)` contains only integers between `x` and `y`.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi then how should we check that . we need to compare them in float type ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaSai Using `>` and `<=` , I have answered it below with a detailed description.

Comment: i am solving this on a coding platform , i have tried with print statements and that works , but getting error with hidden testcases

Answer (score 4):

You need to indent your code. But also, you are creating an empty array every time it runs the loop.
Do it like this:

```
grade = []
for item in students_avg:
    if item >= 90:
        grade.append('A+')
    elif item in range(80,90):
        grade.append('A')
    elif item in range(70,80):
        grade.append('B')
    elif item in range(60,70):
        grade.append('C')
    elif item in range(50,60):
        grade.append('D')
    elif item < 50 :
        grade.append('F')
print(grade)
```

Answer (score 3):

you are creating empty `grade` list everytime you go thru the students_avg, that's why you are getting only one result.

Just do it like:

```
def calculateGrade(
        students_marks
        ):
    # Write your code here

    students_avg = []
    for j in students_marks:
        sume = 0
        for i in j:
            sume = sume + i
        avg = sume / (len(j))
        students_avg.append(avg)
    print(students_avg)

    grade = []
    for item in students_avg:
        if item >= 90:
            grade.append('A+')
        elif 80 <= item < 90:
            grade.append('A')
        elif 70 <= item < 80:
            grade.append('B')
        elif 60 <= item < 70:
            grade.append('C')
        elif 50 <= item < 60:
            grade.append('D')
        elif item < 50:
            grade.append('F')
    return grade


print(calculateGrade([[90,89.9], [90,90]]))

Prints:
# [89.95, 90.0]
# ['A', 'A+']
```

Or a little more elegant solution

```
rating = {
    'A+': [90, 100],
    'A': [80, 90],
    'B': [70, 80],
    'C': [60, 70],
    'D': [50, 60],
    'F': [0, 50]}


def calculate_averages(
        students_marks
):
    students_avg = [sum(student) / len(student) for student in students_marks]
    return students_avg


def get_grade(
        averages
):
    grades = []
    for item in averages:
        for k, v in rating.items():
            if v[0] <= item < v[1]:
                grades.append(k)
    return grades


if __name__ == "__main__":
    points = [[90, 89.9], [90, 90]]
    print(get_grade(calculate_averages(points))) # Prints ['A', 'A+']
```

Comment: when ran individually i am getting correct result . i tried adding this to another block of code and it is returning a the single output again

Comment: @ChaitanyaSai it is really depending on the other code as well. But check the answer from user. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69335707/10306224, bcs this was not visible too much and he is right. You can edit your post so we can take a look.

Comment: updated the entire code , please check once

Comment: Do you have an example of students_marks so we can work with the same input? :)

Comment: sure i will that as well

Comment: @ChaitanyaSai check if the answer works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your grade is `float` you can't use range like below:

```
>>> 50.6 in range(50,60)
False
```

If you want to use your code you can use round() like below:

```
>>> round(50.6) in range(50,60)
True
```

or you can try this:

```
dct_rng = {'A+':[90,100], 'A':[80,90], 'B' :[70,80], 
           'C':[60,70], 'D':[50,60], 'F':[0,50]}

grade = []
students_avg = [50.6 ,48]

for item in students_avg:
    for k,v in dct_rng.items():
        if v[0] < item <= v[1]:
            grade.append(k)
```

Output:

```
['D', 'F']
```

Comment: Good observation as well.

Comment: @user1740577 This takes extra space for creating a dictionary and has more code complexity. Why have extra overhead when we can directly use comparison with equivalent amount of code? Although it is indeed a nice alternative to explore `round()` for this.

Comment: @Zenquiorra first thanks a lot, then I say: I do not agree with you, this helps to readability and we can escape from `if .. elif... elif ... elif ... else` with only one `dictionary`. third: This is one solution. OP and other users can read all solutions and decide what is better for them.

Comment: @Zenquiorra There is no reason to write the comparison and the append more than once. If you had 78 grades possible (A+, A, A-, ..., Z-), would you not use a dictionnary? Plus you can generate the dictionnary automatically which you cannot do with hand written comparisons.

Comment: @user1740577 I agree that for some it may be more readable, but it's a matter of personal preference, although escaping `if ...elif...` at the cost of manually defining a dictionary by putting individual values may not be a good tradeoff when we have to write equivalent length, much complex, extra space code and higher overhead(for a larger dictionary, this approach becomes much feasible). Of course, the OP can decide what's best for them, rather I was asking why to choose this instead of a simpler approach. Readability is indeed important. Thanks

Comment: @Guimoute For a large number of grades, of course, it becomes much feasible as I said in my comment above. Rather I was asking for this particular case. Also, how is appending reduced by defining a dictionary?

Comment: @Zenquiorra To be honest I would still use a dict for three marks. That makes adding new marks later very easy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs indentation and if you have defined `item` less than 50 outside your for loop, so it is executing the last conditional.

If your code is indeed indented properly and you have made a mistake in pasting your code here, even then your list `grade` needs to be defined outside the loop, because it gets reassigned to `grade = []` for every iteration, and whatever value it had in its previous iteration is gone.

Also, you require non integral values, range() will produce integers in the range, so for `range(m,n)` will have integers : `m , m + 1,... n-1`

So any float, for ex: `m.x` will not be generated in `range(m,n)`, for that comparison, it is better to have `>` and `<`. Also using `range()` is unoptimal because of the extra space it will take.

```py
grade = [] 
for item in student_avg:
    if item >= 90:
        grade.append('A+')
    elif 90 < item <= 80:
        grade.append('A')
    elif 80 < item <= 70:
        grade.append('B')
    elif 70 < item <= 60:
        grade.append('C')
    elif 60 < item <= 50:
        grade.append('D')
    elif item < 50 :
        grade.append('F')

print (grade)
```

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oh the question is edited now. Earlier it had different issues and didn't mention non-integral values. I have modified the answer.